# Java Collections.sort for wildcard list (List<?>)

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting, generics

So I am trying to make a general utility function for sorting Lists of various types (mostly built-in wrappers, and Strings). The sample code is below:

```
public void sortArrays(List<?>... arr) {
    // do here
}
```

And it may be used as follows

```
List<Integer> a = // initialization
List<String> b = // initialization
...

sortArrays(a, b)
```

The function will sort varargs List and I'm planning to use Collections.sort(...) but unfortunately, it does not work on List of capture ofs. Is there a proper workaround or approach to what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want each list to be independently sorted by their *natural ordering*, you can do this by using *raw* generics, however that is not recommended.

```
@SafeVarargs
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
public static void sortArrays(List<? extends Comparable>... lists) {
    for (List<? extends Comparable> list : lists)
        Collections.sort(list);
}
```

```
List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList();
List<String> b = Arrays.asList();
List<Object> c = Arrays.asList();
sortArrays(a, b);
sortArrays(c); // compilation error because Object is not a Comparable
```

Comment: Somehow, this works but it doesn't look neat with all the warnings suppressed. I guess there is no other approach than to do this. Thank you

Comment: @ReiSchneider Solution is to not do this, i.e. to simply call `sort()` for each list: `a.sort(null); b.sort(null);`

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of [`Collections#sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) states that it accepts a `List<T>` as a parameter, where `T` is defined as:

```
<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

Therefore, you should be able to define a similar generic type in your `sortArrays` method:

```
public <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sortArrays(List<T>... arr) {
    for (List<T> list : arr) {
        Collections.sort(list);
    }
}
```

This solution will work if your goal is to pass in lists of a single type. For passing lists of different types, see below.

---

There exists a **hacky** solution that utilizes [raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it), allowing you to pass lists of different types to your `sortArrays` to method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<>(List.of(3, 2, 1));
    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>(List.of("6", "5", "4"));

    sortArrays(integerList, stringList);

    System.out.println(integerList);
    System.out.println(stringList);
}

public static void sortArrays(List<? extends Comparable>... arr) {
    for (List<? extends Comparable> list : arr) {
        Collections.sort(list);
    }
}
```

The output of the above snippet is:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: This will work if the varags list I am going to sort is of the same component type, but what I am trying to achieve is a general, all-purpose utility that can sort varargs list of different types

Comment: @ReiSchneider Thanks for the clarification; I'll see if I can come up with a solution that fits your use-case.